# LINQ IQueryable with List<string> input parameter

Tags: c#, linq, wcf-data-services

The following function works great if I enter one string as a parameter, but I would like to supply it a list of strings, i.e. instead of supplying it the name of one project, e.g. "AccountTracker", I can supply it multiple project names, i.e. "AccountTracker", "GameX", "HR1".  How can I convert my LINQ query to do so?

There is the following relationship Employee(1--*)EmployeeProjects(*--1)Project

```
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployeesByProjects(string project)
{
   var employees = from ep in CurrentDataSource.EmployeeProjects
          .Include("Project")
          .Include("Employee")
       where ep.Project.ProjectName == project
       select ep.Employee;
   return employees;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

send the projects as string list and you can use Contains method as below

```
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployeesByProjects(List<string> projects)
{
   var employees = from ep in CurrentDataSource.EmployeeProjects
          .Include("Project")
          .Include("Employee")
       where projects.Contains(ep.Project.ProjectName)
       select ep.Employee;
   return employees;
}
```

or you can send one string with projects as  `"AccountTracker,GameX,HR1"`

```
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployeesByProjects(string listofprojects)
{
   string[] projects= listofprojects.Split(',');
   var employees = from ep in CurrentDataSource.EmployeeProjects
          .Include("Project")
          .Include("Employee")
       where projects.Contains(ep.Project.ProjectName)
       select ep.Employee;
   return employees;
}
```

Comment: Thought your syntax looked good, but at runtime, I get the following: The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Model.Employee] GetEmployeesByProjects1(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String])' has a parameter 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] projects' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' which is not supported for service operations. Only primitive types are supported as parameters.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:

Comment: use data contract for list of projects and send that as parameter

Comment: Ahh... that works!  I had actually put both methods into my code and even though I was only trying to access the first method, the service complained about the other methods of List<>.  Thanks!!!